# What would be a better way to initialize scope variables with server-side data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, playframework

I have a Scala-Play 2.5.x & AngularJS 1.x application and would like to implement a common use-case where tooltip information is displayed for the selected html input. The message text is in the messages as part of Scala-Play i18n `conf/messages.en`

```
myapp.deltaHedgeType.daily=Hedges daily
myapp.deltaHedgeType.interval=Hedges once per optimal hedge frequency in days.
myapp.deltaHedgeType.etc=
```

I'd like the `select` input to show as tooltip the i18n text that corresponds to the selected choice i.e.

```
<select data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{tooltipForSelected}}" ...
```

I need to pass those externalized messages from the server into the angular controller. One way I found to do it is illustrated [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/YdQcX/2/):

```
@import play.api._

@()(implicit messages: MessagesApi, config: Configuration)

<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller="MyController" 
         ng-init="daily='@messages("myapp.deltaHedgeType.daily")'; interval='@messages("myapp.deltaHedgeType.interval")'; ...">
    </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't seem that clean. Making a remote service call from AngularJS to the server only to get the corresponding tooltip seems an overkill even if done only once. Is there a better way?

Comment: could be a server-side rendered constant an option?

Comment: @InferOn thank you! sure, these values won't change dynamically.

Comment: I used [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next) in a project to perform it. With an initialisation in a locale js file. It seems overkill but the result is very flexible without extra xhr calls. Extra point angularjs works well with i18next.. If you're interested, I can give you a example (tomorrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way somewhat cleaner than the one in the OP is rendering a Json object on the server side and passing the result as a value in AngularJS.

```
// app/view/index.scala.html

@import play.api._

@()(implicit messagesApi: MessagesApi, config: Configuration)

<script>
    angular.module("deltaHedgerApp").value("descriptionPerDeltaHedgeType", {
        '@DeltaHedgeType.Daily.toString': '@messagesApi("myapp.deltaHedgeType.daily")',
        '@DeltaHedgeType.SpecifiedInterval.toString': '@messagesApi("myapp.deltaHedgeType.specifiedInterval")',
        // ...
    });
</script>
```

and then on the Controller simply let AngularJS inject the `descriptionPerDeltaHedgeType` data i.e.

```
// client/controllers/MyCtrl.ts

class MyCtrl {
    constructor(private $scope:IMyCtrlScope, private descriptionPerDeltaHedgeType: any) {
        $scope.descriptionPerDeltaHedgeType = descriptionPerDeltaHedgeType;
        // ...
    }
}
```

but maybe there is yet a better way ...